# How to add a text before the sorting option in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've been looking around the net but all they have is to teach you how to add/edit/remove an option in the sorting dropdown. But my template requires me to add a 'Sort By' text. Like this:

[image: oo]

I tried adding it via Jquery but it keeps being gone after ajax filters.

Comment: can you show us your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't rank this down, there might be someone who forgot that there is a format file for this in themes/woocomerce/loop/orderby.php

Then just edit the code like this:

```
<form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">
<span class="sort-name">Sort By</span>
<select name="orderby" class="orderby">
    <?php foreach ( $catalog_orderby_options as $id => $name ) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $id ); ?>" <?php selected( $orderby, $id ); ?>>
            <?php echo esc_html( $name ); ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="paged" value="1" />
<?php wc_query_string_form_fields( null, array( 'orderby', 'submit', 'paged', 'product-page' ) ); ?>
```